# козёл и лошадь на винительный падеж

Tags: падежи

Вот что я заметил:
козёл (мужской род) : (родительный падеж) козла козлов == (винительный падеж) козла козлов
лошадь (женский род) : (родительный падеж) лошади лошадей =/= (винительный падеж) лошадь лошадей (а не лошади лошадей)
Зачем так ? Зачем эта различия на единственное число ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы заметили называется **тип склонения**.
Существует всего 3 типа склонения существительных по падежам https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/sklonenie-sushestvitelnyh.
Лошадь склоняется по 3-му типу, а козел по 2-му.

Comment: вот это точно! не знал об этом! спасибо огромное!